# jQuery create element fires onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I create a anchor using jQuery and the onclick event seems be triggered when the element is created. I've used [this method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) of creating elements a few times with this project without a problem, have I got the wrong end of the stick?

```
jQuery('<a/>', {
    href: '#',
    name: 'link_html_edit',
    id: 'link_html_edit',
    html: 'input HTML text',
    onclick: alert('test')
}).appendTo(spanDefaultValue);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `alert('test');` and assigning it's return value to `onclick`. Use this instead:

```
onclick: function(){ alert('test'); }
```

Since I'm sure `alert('test')` is just an example I should also point out that if you have the same problem with some function you likely can just change your code from:

```
onclick: somefunction()
```

To:

```
onclick: somefunction
```

You only need to wrap it in an anonymous function the way I did with `alert('test');` if you're passing arguments to the function other than the `event` object that is normally passed to an event handler.

Comment: *facepalm* didn't think of that thank you. I will accept in T minus 11 minutes

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the jQuery documentation on this page you should be doing this:

```
$("<a/>", {
   href: '#',
    name: 'link_html_edit',
    id: 'link_html_edit',
    html: 'input HTML text',
  click: function(){
     alert('test');
  }
}).appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 5):

This is much better alternative

```
$("<a/>", {
   href: '#',
    name: 'link_html_edit',
    id: 'link_html_edit',
    html: 'input HTML text'
}).bind('click',function(){ // your function}).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: I get this error with that example: 
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': '<a/>' is not a valid selector.    at <anonymous>:1:1
Seems sensible though...